# sql developer Mac OS connection error

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am getting a weird problem, 
I have an oracle database on amazon aws 
I can connect  using sql developer running on a pc but when I try to connect using the same software on a Mac It shows this error:

> An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
>
> IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
>
> Vendor code 17002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using RDS? Have you checked if this software you're using in your mac takes use of a different port to connect to your db on aws? If that's the case you'll need to add this to your security group from your aws console.

Comment: I was thinking IP address as well

Comment: Yes i am using RDS but i am using the same settings on both Os